# Correlation coefficient for multiple files

Tags: gnuplot, correlation

Im trying a scatterplot from multiple data files.
I want to get a linear fit through into the plot and I want to write the correlation coefficient into the plot.
This I want to do for certain lines in those datafiles.
That is my linear fit:

```
fit [0:1] [0:1000] f(x) '< for i in data_1.csv data_2 data_3.csv \
data_4.csv data_5.csv; do cat "$i"; echo; done' every ::121::361 using 5:27 via a,b
```

this works....
Now It would be great to get the correlation coefficient the same way ...

```
stats '< for i in data_1.csv data_2 data_3.csv \
data_4.csv data_5.csv; do cat "$i"; echo; done' every ::121::361 using 5:27 "Correlation C."
```

this does not work
I get this error:

```
format must have 1-7 conversions of type double (%lf)
```

some update:

this is the output for my fit

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -410.518         +/- 32.5         (7.918%)
b               = 746.018          +/- 5.448        (0.7302%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                a      b      
a               1.000 
b              -0.695  1.000
```

I am not sure that the output works with my bash script to fit a curve through multiple files. A slope of -410.518 seems strange.

Updated question: Does this fitting work in gnuplot with multiple files? The actual Plot looks good but why are there so strange values in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply a syntax error, remove the `"Correlation C."` from the `stats` command, or use `name` to give a prefix other than `STATS_` for the generated variables:

```
stats '...' name 'CorrelationC_'
show variables CorrelationC_
```

And, you could simplify your call by using e.g. `awk` to merge all files (which also works, if the data files don't have a new line in their last line, in contrast to `cat data_*.csv`):

```
cmd = '< awk "//" data_*.csv'
stats cmd every ::121::361 using 5:27
...
plot cmd ...
```

Comment: That works Thank You.... I thought with `"Correlation C."`I could name the correlation coefficient and plot it somewhere in the plot....

Comment: and for my other question? the slope is -410.518 is that a valuable number for a slope?

Comment: You must use the `name` option for `stats` to select a prefix for the generated variables: `stats ... name 'CorrelationC'`. Note, that you cannot have spaces or punctuation characters in the name since the target are variable names. With `show variables CorrelationC` you can see all variables which have been generated. If the value of your slope is correct, I don't know since I don't know your data